# Why does vue lose data of nested component in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I created fiddles to show the unexplicable behaviour:

### Expected behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/o7c9mwzf/27/

When I click unshift, I prepend an element to my items array. then I click set data to set its data, and finally when I click unshift again the element will be unshifted and keep its data.

### Unexpected behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/o7c9mwzf/25/

In this fiddle I put my component inside a div, and the v-for is on the div, like so:

`<div v-for="item in items"><comp :key="item.uuid"/></div>`

and in this case, when I unshift the array, the items that are already in the array lose their data.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour? I couldn't find any in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The key are supposed to be on root component of the `v-for` element, so in this case it's supposed to be the `div`, not the `comp`

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.uuid"><comp /></div>
```

Or you can put the `:key` on the `comp` if you are using `template` instead

```
<template v-for="item in items" :key="item.uuid"><comp /></template>
```

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key

From: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#maintaining-state

Since you put the `key` on the `comp`, the state on the parent element (`div`) isn't maintained.